# Get DataGridColumns Binding Path from DataGridColumnHeader with MultiBinding in DataGridHeader Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, multibinding, commandparameter

Within my DataGridColumnHeaderStyle I have the following MultiBinding:

```
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.AddFilterColumnCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiCommandParameterConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
                    <Binding Path="Column.Binding.Path.Path" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

I am having trouble with the second binding. It always returns `{{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}}`

However if, while the application is running, I change the RelativeSource Mode to something else then back again it works fine.

I have been scratching my head over this for a while now and having viewed no end of other SO questions and using Google I cannot seem to find an answer to why this is or how I can overcome it.

EDIT: 
This is my converter code in case it helps

```
class MultiCommandParameterConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    { return values.Clone(); }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    { return new object[] { value }; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need from your binding you could do something like this -

```
<Setter.Value>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiCommandParameterConverter}">
        <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
        <Binding Path="DisplayIndex" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
        <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Setter.Value>
```

The problem with column header is that the binding associated with that column isn't available via header's Datacontext so you are stuck with doing something like this. Or if you know the property that you will always access you can also Do something like this -

```
<Binding Path="DataContext.PropertyX" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
```

Comment: I managed to solve it by setting the ColumnHeaderStyle within the DataGrid itself rather than in the UserControl.Resources and it seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

OK I seem to of resolved it.

Rather than setting the style in my `<UserControl.Resources>` I applied it in `<DataGrid>` itself.

I have been setting my styles in the `<UserControl.Resources>` so they apply to all the controls on the UserControl but it seems in this case I need to set the ColumnHeaderStyle within the actual `<DataGrid>` for the MultiBinding to work.

Rather than just delete the question I decided to put this as my answer for anyone else who may stumble across this.